# Failed to open the referenced table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new with SQL and I am not entirely sure why I am getting the error: ERROR 1824 (HY000) at line 5: Failed to open the referenced table 'products'
Operation failed with exitcode 1

Here is my code

```
drop database if exists cc;
create database cc /*!40100 default character set utf8 */;
use cc;

create table Customers(
  CustomerID int not null,
  FirstName varchar(255),
  LastName varchar(255),
  address varchar(255),
  phoneNO varchar(11),
  prodID int,
  quantity int,
  primary key (CustomerID),
  foreign key (prodID) references Products(itemID)
);

create table Employees(
   EmployeeID int not null,
   FirstName varchar(255),
   LastName varchar(255),
   address varchar(255),
   phoneNO varchar(11),
   ManagerID int not null,
   primary key (EmployeeID),
   foreign key (managerID) references Managers(mgrID)
 );

create table Managers(
    mgrID int not null,
    salary float,
   MaxSupervisingCapacity int,
   foreign key (mgrID) references Employees(EmployeeID),
   primary key (mgrID) 
);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery, which is a JavaScript library?

Comment: You can't have `references Products` until after you create the `Products` table.

Comment: Also make sure you use the same engine in that table. For me, it showed me the same error. I had accidentally used a different engine for that table

Answer (score 22):

You can't create a foreign key that references another table until after you create that other table. In the `Customers` table you have

```
foreign key (prodID) references Products(itemID)
```

but there's no `Products` table yet. And in `Employees` you have

```
foreign key (managerID) references Managers(mgrID)
```

but the `Managers` table is created after it.

You need to reorder your table creations. Create `Products` before `Customers`.

Also, you can't have circular foreign key relationships. `Employees.managerID` references `Managers` and `Managers.mgrID` references `Employees`. This creates a chicken-and-egg problem: how would you create the first employee, since it needs a manager, but you can't create the first manager because it needs to refer to an employee.

You can solve this problem by allowing the foreign keys to be null. So you create the first employee with a null manager, then create the manager, then replace the `managerID` with this ID.

There's also a chicken-and-egg problem when creating these two tables. You can't reference a table that has yet to be created. So leave out the `foreign key` specification when creating the table, and add it later with `ALTER TABLE`.

```
create table Employees(
   EmployeeID int not null,
   FirstName varchar(255),
   LastName varchar(255),
   address varchar(255),
   phoneNO varchar(11),
   ManagerID int not null,
   primary key (EmployeeID)
 );

create table Managers(
    mgrID int not null,
    salary float,
   MaxSupervisingCapacity int,
   foreign key (mgrID) references Employees(EmployeeID),
   primary key (mgrID) 
);

alter table Employees add foreign key (managerID) references Managers(mgrID);
```

Comment: I get these errors too even though all tables were already created and moved to hibernate. It seems to not be able to reference table that misses a Data Path when clicking on the table and "Table Inspector", is there any reason for that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does "moved to hibernate" mean? What is a Data Path and Table Inspector? It sounds like you're talking about a specific tool that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: We use Spring boot and hibernate to create the tables but we created them manually. Now we want Hibernate to do it. But when we try to make it happen with 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' to 'update' we get the error. All the tables are already created (they were created manually)

Comment: That sounds like a problem with Hibernate. I think `mysqldump` temporarily disables FK checks to deal with problems during the reload process.

Answer (score 17):

You can just surround the whole thing with a

```
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;   

## all of your schema and inserts

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
```

This change of the check will cause the engine not to do checks on those keys and just add them as is.

Comment: A workaround that actually works, but should be used only as a last resort. Most likely the error is genuine and must be cross-checked for the condition mentioned by @Barmar above.

Answer (score 8):

you can try assigning the "ENGINE = INNODB" of the tables when creating them. One of the drawbacks when creating Foreign keys is that, the foreign keys can only be defined for certain storage engines (like InnoDB). The server accepts foreign key definitions for other storage engines but silently ignores them.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
   CustomerID int not null,
   FirstName varchar(255),
   ...

)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

As you can see, when the table is finished, it is assigned the Engine = InnoDB and the default charset.
If you want to alter the table, you can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `Customers` ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

If it served you, do not forget to approve the answer, you can make life easier for many developers.

Comment: This also works for me, I have one database with mixed engines (MyISAM and InnoDB), I changed all MyISAM to InnoDB and now the problem disappears

Answer (score 6):

I have Just fixed this problem by Cheking both tables Storage Engine same and by settings the same Attributes for reff tables column.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and nothing didn´t really work for me until I did the most simple thing. Go to SCHEMAS select the one that has de databases you are trying to work with and with right click, select set as default schema. That´s all, it worked perfectly.
Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: which program do you use?